# Specify plugins in Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt

If I want to use a build.scala file in order to build my project (instead of build.sbt)

how do I specify the plugins?

I want to use the sbt-assmbly plugin. and I am aware that I can create a plugins.sb file and do a addSbtPlugin there.

But i want to put all my build logic in build.scala instead of the sbt files.

Comment: what version of sbt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. You *can* put it in `project/project/Build.scala`, which would let you avoid `.sbt` files, but probably isn't what you want.

The thing is, `project` directory is itself an SBT project, and SBT handles `project/*.sbt` files and `project/project/*.scala` files in it just the same as it does on the top level; but by the time it's working with `project/Build.scala`, it's too late to add plugins.